# Do something with checkbox both initially and on change using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some checkboxes in a form. When they are checked, a hidden field is added to the form.

A couple of the checkboxes are checked initially, and I don't want to modify the HTML to include the related hidden fields. Instead, I want to be able to trigger the same code to add the hidden fields automatically when the page loads initially.

I have tried something like this, but with no luck:

```
container.find("input[data-subscribe]").on("change load", function()
// ------------------------------------------------^^^^ Thought adding load here
//                                                      might do what I want.
{
    var lists = $(this).data("subscribe").toString();
    lists = lists.split(";");

    for(var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++)
    {
        var list = lists[i];

        if($(this).is(":checked")) container.prepend('<input type="hidden" name="lists" value="' + list + '">');
        else container.find("input[type=hidden][value=" + list + "]").remove();
    }

});
```

Of course I could just copy the code and put it in a `$(document).ready()` handler, but if there's just an event I can add to the above `on`, that would be much cleaner.

Comment: You should extract the code to create the hidden fields into function, than just call that function both from `change` handler and on `document.ready`

Comment: FYI: The reason behind this is that the checkboxes act as optins to lists that are in Taguchimail, and the integration requires those hidden fields to determine which lists the user will be added to.

Comment: @J0HN Sure, but again not as streamlined as if there's a relevant event I can just add here.

Comment: @MartyWallace: That's the cleanest way IMO. Why complicate it?

Comment: @MartyWallace one day you might want to add those hiddens on some other event. Or have a little bit different logic in any of those handlers. The separation of event handler and function to do the real work will be extremely handy in that case. So it's an (1) obvious, (2) clean and (3) scalable way to do this. Do you have any *real* reasons to do it some other way? :)

Comment: @J0HN Your reasons are perfectly valid, and ones that I am aware of. I suppose I was *more* interested in knowing if this can be done in general. I should have thought of a separate example that was less arguable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On dom ready just trigger the change event

```
container.find("input[data-subscribe]").change()
```

Or

```
container.find("input[data-subscribe]").trigger('change')
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a function and call it from both handlers:

```
function someCheckboxfunction(lists) {
    lists = lists.split(";");

    for(var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++)
    {
        var list = lists[i];

        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            container.prepend('<input type="hidden" name="lists" value="' + list + '">');
        }
        else {
            container.find("input[type=hidden][value=" + list + "]").remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Calling code

```
$(document).ready(function() {        
    container.find(("input[data-subscribe]").on("change", function() { 
        someCheckboxFunction($(this).data("subscribe").toString()) 
    });

    var lists = container.find("input[data-subscribe]").data("subscribe").toString();
    someCheckboxFunction(lists);
});
```

Comment: Might want to take a close look at what you've done here. What does `$(this)` refer to in `someCheckboxfunction`? Also I'm pretty sure the initial step will only apply to one checkbox.

Comment: You're right, too much copy paste. However since you're questioning it I can see you understand the general concept.